# native-crypto encrypt throwing DOMException

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, cryptography

I am using the `native-crypto` package which is an API for cross-platform cryptography (so web and node.js).

```
let crypto = require("native-crypto");
```

I have generated a public/private key-pair...

```
keyPair = crypto.generate('P-256');
```

...and I am trying to encrypt a message like so:

```
let message = "Hello, World!";
let encrypted = crypto.rsa.encrypt(keyPair.privateKey, message);
```

However, this is not working, I am receiving a `DOMException` (in a browser environment) with no further details.

How do I solve this?

Possible issues:

- Maybe I am using the incorrect combination of functions
- It could be because my generated key's `key_ops` only includes `["sign"]` but nothing for encrypion.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the exception...for some reason you're not seeing the error message.

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The required JWK member "kty" was missing
```

## Asynchronous vs synchoronous

This first error is because you're trying to use an *asynchonous* API *synchronously*.

You need to add the `await` keyword on the `keyPair` generate line:

```
keyPair = await crypto.generate('P-256');
```

Without the `await` keyword, a Promise is assigned to `keyPair` instead of an Object containing `kty`.

## Wrong key type

Once you fix that, you'll see another error:

```
The JWK "kty" member was not "RSA"
```

This is because an ECDSA key is being used with RSA encryption.

## One more problem

Once you fix that, you'll see one more error

```
The JWK "key_ops" member was inconsistent with that specified by the Web Crypto call. The JWK usage must be a superset of those requested
```

I can't help with this one. I suspect that this is an issue with `native-crypto`. You might have to file a bug report on their [github repo](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/native-crypto/issues). Here is a roughly equivalent example using only the Web Crypto API.

```
const crypto = window.crypto.subtle;

async function main() {
  const keyPair = await crypto.generateKey(
    {
      name: "RSA-OAEP",
      modulusLength: 4096,
      publicExponent: new Uint8Array([1, 0, 1]),
      hash: "SHA-256"
    },
    true,
    ["encrypt", "decrypt"]
  );

  let message = "hello";

  message = new TextEncoder().encode(message);
  const encrypted = await crypto.encrypt({ name: "RSA-OAEP" }, keyPair.publicKey, message);

  console.log(encrypted);
}

main()
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll took a look soon. And, my bad, I had the `await` keyword, but forgot to include it in the question.

Comment: @DavidCallanan all good. You never know. What browser are you using/why can't you see the error message attached to the DOMException?

Comment: That's funny... 3 weeks later and I can now see the error message in my browser (and I haven't touched the code since)

Comment: @DavidCallanan weird !